# Thumbnails limit max first 6 images

Tags: 7, entities, media

I'm using Drupal 7 and create a module for my content thumbnail images frontpage display. Working this:

```
 if(count($p_detail->field_slide) > 0){
            $output .= '<div class="right">';
            $output .= '<ul class="thumbs">';
            $i=6;
            foreach($p_detail->field_slide['und'] as $thumb):
                $img_path = $thumb['uri'];
                $img_url = image_style_url('tmb_240x117', $img_path);
                $img_file = '<img src="'.$img_url.'" alt="'.$p_detail->title.'" />';


                $output .= '<li>
                                <a href="'.$p_url.'">
                                    '.$img_file.'
                                    <div class="shadow"></div>    
                                    <div class="hoverimg"></div>
                                 </a>
                                <div class="img_no">0'.$i.'</div>
                            </li>';
                $i--;
            endforeach;
            $output .= '</ul>';
            $output .= '</div>';
        }
```

My thumbnails, field_slide and i want only first 6 thumbnails (if have 6 images... for exam, have 2 images, display 2 thumbnails)

How can i do this?

Comment: why are you not using a for() loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then you just need to [break](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) out of the foreach loop after you got 6 thumbnails saved in the `$output` variable. With that addition the end of your loop would look like this:

```
if ($i == 1) break;
$i--;
endforeach;
```